# C simple queue code stuck running while inserting

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

```
    /* Queues */
/* Linear Queues */
#include  <stdio.h>
#define MAX 10
int queue[MAX];
int rear=-1;front=-1;
void insert(void);
int delete_element(void);
int peek(void);
void display(void);
int main(){
    int option;
    printf("\n\n ***** MAIN MENU *****"); 
     printf("\n 1. Insert an element");    
    printf("\n 2. Delete an element");    
    printf("\n 3. Peek");   
    printf("\n 4. Display the queue");   
    printf("\n 5. EXIT");    
    printf("\n Enter your option : ");    
    scanf("%d", &option);    
    switch(option){
        case 1:
            insert();
            break;
        case 2:
            int val;
            val = delete_element();
            if(val != -1)
              printf("\n The number deleted is :%d", val);
            break;
        case 3:
            val = peek();
            if(val != -1)
              printf("\n the first value in queue is: %d", val);
            break;
        case 4:
            display();
            break;
    }while(option !=5);
    return 0;
}
void insert(){
    int num;
    printf("\n Enter the number to be inserted in the queue : "); 
    scanf("%d", &num);
    if (rear == MAX-1){
        printf("Queue is full");
    }
    else if(front == -1 && rear == -1){
        front = rear = 0; /* If queue is empty, set front and rear to 0 */
    }
    else{
        rear++; /* Increment rear */
        queue[rear] = num;
    }
}
int delete_element(){
    int val;
    if(front == -1 || front>rear){
        printf("Queue is empty");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        val=queue[front];
        front++;
        if(front>rear){
            front = rear = -1; /* Front > rear = queue empty */
        }
        return val; /* Return popped value */
    }
}
int peek(){
    if(front == -1 || front>rear){
        printf("Queue is empty");
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        return queue[front];
    }
}
void display(){
    int i;
    printf("\n");
    if(front == -1 || front>rear){
        printf("Queue is empty");
    }
    else{
        for(i=front;i<=rear;i++){
            printf("\t %d",&queue[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Code gets stuck while I try to insert element "3".

[image]

I am following Data Structures using C book, so I am not sure they would write a broken code to the book, but this just boggled my mind. It is running for 4 minutes, without doing literally anything. Neither deleting, peeking, inserting, displaying everything gets stuck in a loop.

Comment: `while(option !=5);` is the infinite loop; preceding block belongs to `switch()`. Which book, ISBN or Author-Title?

Comment: In your `insert` function, are you sure about the order in which you do `rear++` and `queue[rear] = num`?

Comment: C in title, C book, C code. What made you add the C++ tag?

Comment: What is the difference between the shown code and the code in the book?

Comment: Thanks for deleting the C++ tag. But I would really like to know what made you add it. I ask because you are by far not the only one making that mistake and I would like to try and find something to change about the tagging so that users are not misguided like that in the future.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah, same as the book.

Comment: @Yunnosch no difference, just some comments to self for learning

Comment: @Yunnosch misclick. sorry for double tag lol.

Comment: A misclick is not enough of an explanation. You would also have to leave it tagged after you misclicked and still leave it there after seeing the question finally appear.

Comment: Regarding the `insert` thing, in the order you do it now, you increase `rear` to `1` so you set `queue[1]` to `val. That means you never use index `0` of the array. I haven't checked the other functions, but if you decrement in the wrong order you could then attempt to dequeue `queue[0]` which haven't been set.

Comment: It isnt working again... https://pastebinp.com/ar7Sl8Cdifj4MUG6M3RQ#tmN9Tt7zwl7s59xaM6rB-3lgDjwkWK-1Ox7gVnsgs14= Did the hotfixes you guys advised, now do/while loop works but insert function still loops itself. That code was exactly same from book :/

Comment: https://prnt.sc/KDS8OPCb5cLz Like am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You have the code (abbreviated):

```
switch(option){
    ...
}while(option !=5);
```

Slightly reformatted it's the same as:

```
switch(option){
    ...
}

while(option !=5)
{
}
```

That is, your `switch` ends and then you have an infinite loop.

I'll guess you really wanted to do an `do-while` loop around the menu and switch:

```
do
{
    // Print menu
    // Get input
    // Switch
} while (option != 5);
```